# tensorboardX add_graph（）ImportError: cannot import name 'OperatorExportTypes'

Tags: tensorboardx

When i use the tensorbosrdX :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter


class Net1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net1, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(20)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2)
        x = F.relu(x) + F.relu(-x)
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x


dummy_input = torch.rand(13, 1, 28, 28)

model = Net1()
with SummaryWriter(comment='Net1') as w:
    w.add_graph(model, (dummy_input,))
```

`
I get this  error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/pych/tensorboardtest.py", line 34, in <module>
    w.add_graph(model, (dummy_input,))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/jointpy35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboardX/writer.py", line 566, in add_graph
    self.file_writer.add_graph(graph(model, input_to_model, verbose))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/jointpy35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboardX/pytorch_graph.py", line 171, in graph
    from torch.onnx.utils import OperatorExportTypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'OperatorExportTypes'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And this code is an example of how to use add_graph().But it cant work in my computer and i dont know how to solve it
My environment:

1. torch : 0.4.0
2. python:3.5.0
3. tensorboardX 1.6

Comment: The version of torch is wrong updata the version of pytorch to 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

you need update the version of pytorch to 1.0.1